# Setup a Visit Website and Send to Mobile link on facebook app

Tags: facebook

I cannot find any information on this in the developers guide.  I'm setting up a facebook app so users can connect and publish content to their feed. I want to create a page that looks like this: https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/houzzapp

On the right side you will see the two blue buttons, one that says Visit Website, the other Send to Mobile.  These are the functions that I want as far as the facebook app is concerened.  Does anyone know how to do this or can point me to some documentation or a tutorial?

Comment: Are you able to solve it ? I am stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is **Facebook's App Center**.

In order to get your App on Facebook's App Center you have to go through a Approval which you can review/edit and submit via `Your App -> App Details`.

Once all necessary Fields and Pictures are uploaded, you can `Submit App Detail Page`.

Pointing out the Specific questions about Facebook's App Center:

**Visit Website button**: Will use the link you entered in your Basic Settings under `Website with Facebook Login`

**Mobile Web**: Will use the *mobile version url* you entered in your Basic Settings under `Mobile Web`